# [FREERADIUS - Conf/Logging]

Tags: logging, configuration, freeradius

Is there a specific configuration on FreeRadius to set up the rate of the production of the file.log ?
Please could you share the configuration for the logging?

Thanks a lot for your support

naiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the FreeRADIUS config to limit logging, neither in the main log (from `radiusd.conf`) or in e.g. the `linelog` module. You need to make sure that wherever you are logging to (file, syslog, etc) has the capacity to cope, or filter/drop log messages there.

If file logging cannot keep up with the amount of log entries produced (unusual, you must have a very large system) then you would be better to either look at reducing the amount of logging, or customising it (by using e.g. linelog and disabling the main radiusd logging), or feeding it with syslog to another logging system that can keep up with demand.